# angular material slider not sliding smoothly

Tags: angular, angular-material

working with angular cli 6

i added angular material and hammerjs, the slider is working but not smoothly(when dragging it snaps and stucks) not like in the official site of material where it works perfect

i tried to import hammerjs everywhere(all the solutions say to import it in different places), but still the same problem.

does anyone know the problem and how to fix it?

thx

my slider has nothing special

```
<mat-slider class="progressSlider" #matslider >

</mat-slider>
```